# Downloading an image from twitter with libcurl C++

Tags: c++, curl, twitter

I'm making a program that takes a person's tweet, and if it contains an image, download it.


Why can I download an image from this URL (Example #1)

http://www.google.co.id/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png

And not from this URL (Example #2)

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DR-kkH4XcAAQ-vc.jpg&imgrefurl=https://twitter.com/officialmcafee/status/945655402276024320&h=1200&w=992&tbnid=0q3B6ZB_UxjRIM&tbnh=247&tbnw=204&usg=__xvjbjSSMvuImESBLVvBBrUagUe8=&docid=vdqkoUmaefYoFM


**Example #1**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CURL *image;
    CURLcode imgresult;
    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    const char *url = "http://www.google.co.id/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    image = curl_easy_init();
    if (image)
    {
        // Open file 
        fp = fopen("img.png", "wb");
        if (fp == NULL) cout << "File cannot be opened";

        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        // Grab image 
        imgresult = curl_easy_perform(image);
        if (imgresult)
            cout << "Cannot grab the image!\n";
    }
    // Clean up the resources 
    curl_easy_cleanup(image);
    // Close the file 
    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Example #2**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CURL *image;
    CURLcode imgresult;
    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    const char *url = "https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DR-kkH4XcAAQ-vc.jpg&imgrefurl=https://twitter.com/officialmcafee/status/945655402276024320&h=1200&w=992&tbnid=0q3B6ZB_UxjRIM&tbnh=247&tbnw=204&usg=__xvjbjSSMvuImESBLVvBBrUagUe8=&docid=vdqkoUmaefYoFM";
    image = curl_easy_init();
    if (image)
    {
        // Open file 
        fp = fopen("img.png", "wb");
        if (fp == NULL) cout << "File cannot be opened";

        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        // Grab image 
        imgresult = curl_easy_perform(image);
        if (imgresult)
            cout << "Cannot grab the image!\n";
    }
    // Clean up the resources 
    curl_easy_cleanup(image);
    // Close the file 
    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you're obviously getting an `HTTP` redirect  from google. Not familiar with libcurl, but it's possible that there's an option that can be set to automatically follow `HTTP` redirects. If not, you will have to do more work to extract the real URL from Google's response, and attempt to download from the real URL.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But even if I use the address of the original image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DR-kkH4XcAAQ-vc.jpg it still doesn't work

Comment: I had no problems, whatsoever, using the curl command line client to download the image from the URL you included in your comment. Like I said, I am no familiar with libcurl, a brief Google search found the documentation for libcurl, and after reading `curl_easy_setopt()`'s documentation, and looking at your code, it seems obvious why you don't download anything. That's what you told the library to do: not download anything. You set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to `NULL`. Seems you told the library to ignore everything it downloads (no write function). So what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing man, but I changed the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and it still won't download.

Comment: Just switched it back to NULL. Now it works. I have no idea what was going on.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik read the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) more carefully: "*Set [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION] to NULL to get the internal default function used instead of your callback. The internal default function will write the data to the FILE * given with CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.*"

Comment: @user9143463 [`curl_easy_perform()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) has a return value. If it is not 0, it tells you WHY the download failed. You did not say what that value actually was when things were not using. You can also use the [`CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html) option to get a human readable error message when things fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a link to an image. This is html page. Note, that your code doesn't download any image the *html* page refers to, but just *html* page.

Second, you are not following redirects. Add one more option:

```
curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Third, you'd better to pretend to be a browser:

```
curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");
```

Once I added both options, I managed to download your link.